# how to hide parent location hash in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello everyone I wanted to do is to switch form using single page (show/hide using javascript) but everytime i refreshd the page it will go back to the default form. Now i have a javascript code that will make the current form stays even if the users refresh the page it wont go back the the default form.

My problem is with my current script it makes a hash title in the url...how to make the hash hide without affecting the function of the script? or is there any other tricks in doing this in jquery/javascript? can anyone help me please?

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){
    $('.myFirst').hide();
    $('.mySecond').hide();
    $('.myThird').hide();
    $('#show_first').click(function(){
        parent.location.hash = 'first';
        $('.myFirst').show();
        $('.mySecond').hide();
        $('.myThird').hide();
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
        return false;
    });
    $('#show_second').click(function(){
        parent.location.hash = 'second';
        $('.myFirst').hide();
        $('.mySecond').show();
        $('.myThird').hide();
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
        return false;
    });
    $('#show_third').click(function(){
        parent.location.hash = 'third';
        $('.myFirst').hide();
        $('.mySecond').hide();
        $('.myThird').show();
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
        return false;
    });
    $('#show_' + parent.location.hash.substr(1)).click();
});
</script>
```

modal link:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Modal Dialog</a>
```

modal dialog code:

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                            <button type="button" id="show_first" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">First</button>
                                            <button type="button" id="show_second" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Second</button>
                                            <button type="button" id="show_third" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Third</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

html code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="myFirst">
            <div class="row">
                <center>
                    First Page
                </center>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySecond">
            <div class="row">
                <center>
                    Second Page
                </center>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="myThird">
            <div class="row">
                <center>
                    Third Page
                </center>
             </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So where current page should be stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the id of the form in cookie and then after page refresh using the id put focus on the form using id of that form.

Answer (score 0):

You can change url of page using HTML5 and pushState https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries